# "Too short input for last message" with the netlink library

Tags: haskell, netlink

This issue is a about how to use the haskell `netlink` library.
The casting (?) mechanism I have trouble with might be a more generic haskell problem, which is why I hope it's ok to ask here.

I previously exposed my problem here: https://github.com/Ongy/netlink-hs/issues/5 but here is summary:

I am trying to use the library `netlink` (https://github.com/Ongy/netlink-hs, on hackage too) to communicate with a kernel module via the netlink protocol.
I receive packets through the `recvOne'` call (called here https://github.com/teto/netlink_pm/blob/v5/hs/daemon.hs#L502):

```
results <- (recvOne' simpleSock) :: IO [Either String MptcpPacket]
```

defined here https://github.com/Ongy/netlink-hs/blob/master/System/Linux/Netlink.hs#L395 as:

```
recvOne' :: (Convertable a, Eq a, Show a) => NetlinkSocket -> IO [Either String (Packet a)]
recvOne' sock = getPackets' <$> recvmsg sock bufferSize
```

but on launch my program stops immediately with

```
daemon.hs: user error (Too short input for last message =.=)
```

My belief is that my `recvOne'` call casts everything to a (big) MptcpPacket

```
type MptcpPacket = Packet GenlData NoDataMptcp
```

straightaway while the stack can send smaller Packets like ErrorMsg/DoneMsg https://github.com/Ongy/netlink-hs/blob/master/System/Linux/Netlink.hs#L115 :

```
data Packet a
        = Packet -- The "normal" message
    {
      packetHeader     :: Header -- ^The netlink message header
    , packetCustom     :: a -- ^The datatype for additional static data for the interface
    , packetAttributes :: Attributes -- ^The netlink attributes
    }
        | ErrorMsg -- The error message
    {
      packetHeader     :: Header -- ^The netlink message header
    , packetError      :: CInt -- ^The error ID for this error message
    , errorPacket      :: Packet a -- ^The offending message
    }
        | DoneMsg -- The done message, this should usually not be seen by a user
    {
      packetHeader     :: Header -- ^The header of the done message
    }
deriving (Eq)
```

My question thus becomes:
 - with this library, how can I retreive all packets and only afterwards distinguish between ErrorMsg / DoneMsg and the valid netlink packets. Haskell forces me to cast to something but it's weird. Should I use some kind of exception ? am I going to lose packets this way ? and so on.

As I am still a haskell beginner, any kind of example/code is welcome

Comment: Can you include code that's causing this issue in the question itself, rather than linking to it? (If it's too big to show here, try making a smaller example with the same problem).

Comment: Is it possible to remove this post ? it seems very specific and endup being solved by an update in the (buggy) library ?